# Count number of comparisons for a binary search

Tags: c#, binary-search

I'm looking to be able to count the amount of times the binary search does a comparison in my code. Basically, the program I'm working on outputs an unsorted array, then the user enters a number and it finds the number in the array, and spits out the number of comparisons it made (bubble swap) and the index it's at. Then it spits out the sorted array and asks for the user to input another number.

The problem:  I can't seem to figure out how to count the number of comparisons the binary search has to do to figure out if the number is in the list of numbers or not.

Code:

```
class Lab3
{
    static int[] intArray = {17,  166,  288,  324,  531,  792,  946,  157,      276,  441, 533, 355, 228, 879, 100, 421, 23, 490, 259, 227,
                             216, 317, 161, 4, 352, 463, 420, 513, 194, 299, 25, 32, 11, 943, 748, 336, 973, 483, 897, 396,
                             10, 42, 334, 744, 945, 97, 47, 835, 269, 480, 651, 725, 953, 677, 112, 265, 28, 358, 119, 784,
                             220, 62, 216, 364, 256, 117, 867, 968, 749, 586, 371, 221, 437, 374, 575, 669, 354, 678, 314, 450,
                             808, 182, 138, 360, 585, 970, 787, 3, 889, 418, 191, 36, 193, 629, 295, 840, 339, 181, 230, 150 };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Prints unsorted array
        PrintArray(intArray);

        // Gets user input and then checks if it's inside the array, if not it outputs that it isn't, that's all this does.
        SearchIntArray(intArray);

        // Bubble swap kicks in and sorts the array
        BubbleSort(intArray);

       // Binary Search kicks in and searches for the second user input to see if it's in the array and gives the index that it's at. 
        BinarySearch(intArray);
     }

   // This checks to see whether or not the int entered by the user is actually in the array, pretty straightforward stuff
    static int SearchIntArray(int[] intArray)
    {
        // get user input to check array for number
        Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is " + guess);

        // sort through array to find the number entered by the user 
        int index = 0;
        int numOfSwaps = 0;
        while (index < intArray.Length && guess != intArray[index])
        {
            index++;
        }
        numOfSwaps = index;
        if (index >= intArray.Length)
            Console.Write("Made 100 comparions, the number " + guess + " was not found in the unsorted array");
        else Console.Write("Made " + (numOfSwaps+1) + " comparisons to find " + guess + " is at index " + index + " in the unsorted array");
       //Adds blank lines
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Number of comparisons: 4884");

        // adds blank lines

        Console.WriteLine();

        int niddleIndex = -1;
         return niddleIndex;
    }
    static int BubbleSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int numOfSwaps = 0;

        // Bubble swap kicks in and sorts the array
        Console.WriteLine("The sorted array: ");
        int temp = 0;

        for (int write = 0; write < intArray.Length; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort < intArray.Length - 1; sort++)
            {
                if (intArray[sort] > intArray[sort + 1])
                {
                    temp = intArray[sort + 1];
                    intArray[sort + 1] = intArray[sort];
                    intArray[sort] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(intArray[i] + ", ");
       //Adds a blank line
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("In total, swapped 2344 times to sort this array");
       //Adds a blank line
        Console.WriteLine();
        return numOfSwaps;
    }


    static int BinarySearch(int[] intArray)
    {
        int x = 101;

        // parses the user input into the int secondInputParsed
        Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        string secondInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int secondInputParsed = Int32.Parse(secondInput);


        int low = 0;
        int high = x - 1;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (secondInputParsed < intArray[mid])
                high = mid - 1;
            else if (secondInputParsed > intArray[mid])
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (secondInputParsed == intArray[mid])
            {

                // Only problem I'm having is to get the number of searches for the binary search, just that, everything else works good! 
                Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Made " + low + " comparisons to find {0} is at index {1} in the sorted array, using Binary Search", secondInputParsed, mid);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press anything to exit the program");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return -1; 
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Made 7 comparisons to find " + secondInput + " is not in the sorted array, using Binary Search");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press anything to exit the program");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return -1;

    }

    //call this method to print an integer array to the console.
    static void PrintArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The unsorted array: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != arr.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, ", arr[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i]);
            }
        }

        // These create 2 blank lines between the printArray and to get the user input. Makes it look nicer, that's all.
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: One way would be to wire up [IComparer<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) into your code and have implementation that would count the calls.

Comment: `while (low <= high){ count++;..`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova that works sort of , half the time it does and the other it doesnt.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I have an .exe file of how it should work 100% and when I compare the results on there sometimes it's correct but other times the # of comparisons will be way off.

Comment: What exactly does it count? the exact number of comparisons you may find starting with 1 (to amend for ==) and incrementing once more after the second if. BTW you don't need ==, if something is not > and is not < it's always == (unless it's undefined, but it's not your case)

Comment: I'm kind of confused

Comment: Assuming by "comparisons" what you really mean is "iterations of the loop" (i.e. how many numbers were actually considered during the search), Nadia's suggestion should work and will give you exactly the number of times the loop iterated. If that's not the count you are trying to obtain, you need to be more clear in your question.

Comment: @JacobNoble if you're still struggling with it, you can provide us with some control values (inputs and outputs of your .exe file). It may help to figure out what you're supposed to count.

Comment: I apologize for not being very clear, I thought I was. I'll get some control values now. Input: 889, output 5, I should be getting 6. Input: 295, output 6, I should get 7. But sometimes it'll work, like if I input 3, I'll get back 6 which is the right answer that I'm supposed to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got different results because your variation works slightly faster in some cases. Binary search depends on how you split the data (i.e. if you've got 7 elements the first group may be 3 or 4 elements and here you may be more or less lucky). However, you start with the wrong value for `high` and it can lead to an exception (try to input 1500 in your program). The array has 100 elements, but they're numbered from 0 to 99, not from 1 to 100. If you start with low = 0 and hight = 100, you array must have 101 elements! Having a wrong `high` you calculate a wrong `mid` and then just get somewhat more lucky than the classical version of the algorithm, which shell look like this:

```
int low = 0;
int high =  intArray.Length - 1;
var count = 0;
while (low <= high)
{
     count++;
     int mid = (low + high) / 2;
     if (secondInputParsed < intArray[mid])
           high = mid - 1;
     else if (secondInputParsed > intArray[mid])
           low = mid + 1;
     else 
     {
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Made {2} comparisons to find {0} is at index {1} in the sorted array, using Binary Search", secondInputParsed, mid, count);
                ...
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("Made {0} comparisons to find {1} is not in the sorted array, using Binary Search", count, secondInput);
```

Comment: I see where the mistake was made, I appreciate that you took the time after a couple of days to still help me out with my problem. t's really helpful.